# Ant Design calendar is not mobile responsive

Tags: reactjs, web, mobile, antd

I have a Ant Design Calendar component on my React website.

```
<Calendar
     value={this.state.value}
     fullscreen={false}
     onPanelChange={this._onPanelChange}
     onSelect={this._onSelect}
     disabledDate={(current) => {
            return current && moment().isAfter(current, "day");
     }}
/>
```

This calendar renders prefectly on dekstop but on mobile it does not render completely. I tried to inspect and change properties but nothing worked out.

On mobile the calendar gets cut off(I get a horizontal scrollbar) and looks like this -

[image]

Any idea how can I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the  component in a div and set a width on it should work.

```
            <div className="calendarWrapper">
               <Calendar
                  className="dateCalendar"
                  selectionMode="single"
                  defaultValue={defaultDateValue}
                  onChange={onChangeDate}
               />
            </div>
```

```
.calendarWrapper {
   border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 390px !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).